# this is about youtube api for logging in and cancelling/subscribing premium subscription?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I basically have not idea about programming but I do know that through API this problem can be solved.

So I am looking to create a saas platform which will help users to subscribe/unsubscribe their youtube premium subscriptions whenever they want as well as pay their subscription amount via us.

Is there any feature of the Youtube API which can help me to solve this problem of mine? If yes then how to go forward with it in details?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @ Souvik Barua: If you really meant it saying that "I basically have not idea about programming", then follows that there's not much we can help you on this forum. Using the Yahoo Data API is really about programming.

Comment: Me not knowing how to program is not the problem.  I want to know if there is any feature of the Youtube API that can allow users on my platform to subscribe and cancel their subscription for youtube premium?

Comment: @  Souvik Barua: As far as I know there's no such API. But other users of the API reading this forum may know better -- wait for other interventions. To better catch others attention, I suggest to change the post's title to a shorter, more to the point text.